# Set an entire row from a MYSQL query as a variable in php

Tags: php

Ok so essentially I have a list of usernames from a query that i want to set as a single variable

So for example

```
Query Result is
username1
username2 
username3

$variable =username1 " ",username2 " ",username3
```

Comment: Define the exact problem you are facing or where are you stuck ?

Comment: So you don't know how to iterate over result set, or how to join strings, or what?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have now? How are you querying the database?

Comment: Why not just use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) (MySQL) or [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) (PHP)?

Comment: I started coding this friday so go easy on me guys. What I am trying to do is grab the names and emails so i can send it to the users through email.

Comment: @CORRUPT I think I'm going to use the implode command set the variables as username or "empty space" because the number of rows will depend on the query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
mysql> SELECT Language FROM CountryLanguage WHERE CountryCode = 'THA';
```

It outputs:

```
    Language
----------------
    Chinese
    Khmer
    Kuy
    Lao
```

To concatenate the values into a single string, you query:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Language) As Languages FROM CountryLanguage
       WHERE CountryCode = 'THA';
```

Then the output will be:

```
Languages
-----------------------
Chinese, Khmer, Kuy, Lao
---------------------------
```

You can also use some format of `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Like

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Language SEPARATOR ‘-’ )`

It will use `‘-’` instead of `‘,’`

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Language ORDER BY Language DESC )`

To change the order and shorting output

Note: `GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values.